# dplyr package - mutate

Tags: r, dplyr

Good night!
I'm brazilian and I don't speak english very well.
I work a database with more than 10000 rows, represented by the example below.

```
df <- data.frame(
    PROCESS = c(180022121, 180022121, 180022105, 180022105, 180022097, 180022097, 180022097, 180022501, 180022501), 
    NAME = c("A_NONIMATO", "B_NONIMATO", "C_NONIMATO", "C_NONIMATO", "D_NONIMATO", "E_NONIMATO", "F_NONIMATO", "G_NONIMATO", "G_NONIMATO"),DATE = c("02/01/2018", "02/01/2018", "01/01/2018", "01/01/2018", "01/01/2018", "01/01/2018", "01/01/2018", "02/01/2018", "02/01/2018"), 
    CRIME = c("ART.33", "ART.33", "ART.35", "ART.33", "ART.155", "ART.155", "ART.155", "ART.157", "ART.14CP"))
```

HYPOTHESIS:

a) same `PROCESS`, different `PARTNAME`, same `CRIME` (lines 1 and 2)

b) same `PROCESS`, same `PARTNAME`, different `CRIME` (lines 3 and 4)

c) same `PROCESS`, same `PARTNAME`, different `CRIME` (lines 8 and 9)

My question concerns hypothesis c: I need to create a column `CRIME2` to transfer `ART.14CP` turning the case into just one line… without moving to hypothesis b. Throughout the database will always be written `ART.14CP`.

To look like this:

```
df2 <- data.frame(
    PROCESS = c(180022121, 180022121, 180022105, 180022105, 180022097, 180022097, 180022097, 180022501),
    NAME = c("A_NONIMATO", "B_NONIMATO", "C_NONIMATO", "C_NONIMATO", "D_NONIMATO", "E_NONIMATO", "F_NONIMATO", "G_NONIMATO"),
    DATE = c("02/01/2018", "02/01/2018", "01/01/2018", "01/01/2018", "01/01/2018", "01/01/2018", "01/01/2018", "02/01/2018"),
    CRIME = c("ART.33", "ART.33", "ART.35", "ART.33", "ART.155", "ART.155", "ART.155", "ART.157"),
    CRIME2 = c("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "ART.14CP"))
```

Thank you very much for your attention.

Comment: Please edit your title to be more descriptive of your problem; also avoid statements such as "help me", "help if you can", etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a slight modification of Ronak's answer using case_when and another way of approaching the logic. I prefer case_when to if or ifelse since it's more intuitive to others reading your code, especially if you need to use multiple conditions or have numerous cases. The TRUE condition will capture any remaining cases; if you don't put it, those cases be set to NA by default.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(PROCESS, NAME) %>%
  mutate(CRIME2 = case_when(
    "ART.14CP" %in% CRIME ~ "ART.14CP",
    TRUE ~ ""
  )) %>% 
  filter(CRIME != "ART.14CP")
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to only have values in `CRIME2` where `CRIME == "ART.14CP"` one way using `dplyr` for each group (`PROCESS` and `NAME`) assign value `"ART.14CP"` only if it is present or else  assign an empty value. We remove the duplicate row entry for `"ART.14CP"` using `filter`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(PROCESS, NAME) %>%
  mutate(CRIME2 = if (any(CRIME == "ART.14CP")) "ART.14CP" else "") %>%
  filter(CRIME != "ART.14CP")


#    PROCESS NAME       DATE       CRIME   CRIME1  
#      <dbl> <fct>      <fct>      <fct>   <chr>   
#1 180022121 A_NONIMATO 02/01/2018 ART.33  ""      
#2 180022121 B_NONIMATO 02/01/2018 ART.33  ""      
#3 180022105 C_NONIMATO 01/01/2018 ART.35  ""      
#4 180022105 C_NONIMATO 01/01/2018 ART.33  ""      
#5 180022097 D_NONIMATO 01/01/2018 ART.155 ""      
#6 180022097 E_NONIMATO 01/01/2018 ART.155 ""      
#7 180022097 F_NONIMATO 01/01/2018 ART.155 ""      
#8 180022501 G_NONIMATO 02/01/2018 ART.157 ART.14CP
```